# Import-StartLayout *.xml is not a valid layout file

Tags: xml, powershell, layout

I try to make a powershell script that import a custom Windows10Pro StartLayout approved by my organisation.

What i do :
First : `Export-StartLayout –path c:\StartLayout.xml`
Like described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout
Then added `<CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>` block to also customize taskbar items described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar

So, my xml file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
        <start:Group Name="Outils" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Office" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Word 2016.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk" />
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.onenoteim" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Excel 2016.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Applications" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Slack Technologies\Slack.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
      <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
        <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
          <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\File Explorer.lnk" />
      <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" /> 
      <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Slack Technologies\Slack.lnk" />
        </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
      </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
    </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Finally, i open a powershell as admin and try to import this xml via `Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath c:\StartLayout.xml –MountPath c:` and there comes the error " *.xml is not a valid layout file " :/

I've searched many usefull websites & forums but can't seem to solve this~

Purpose is to Import this custom StartMenu & Taskbar after a new PC joined the domain (on Windows 2012 server).

I'm no familiar with powershell, nor any programming language but i'm not against learning new things.

Please tell me where i'm wrong :)

Thanks !

P.S.: It's my first post, i hope it's well formated.

Comment: Is the white space before the xml declaration actually there? Or is that a artifact of pasting?  If it's there, try removing it.

Comment: That's my mistake, sorry, edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

The secret lies in the Windows's version. I've made the xml on a top-updated Windows 10 and tried to apply on a not-so-updated Windows 10. First thing was to update my Windows infrastructure (1709 b16.299.192), now it works well.

Also, the taskbar block don't do anything worth for the moment, i'll try that on later.

My xml now looks like this :

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
        <start:Group Name="Applications">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Slack Technologies\Slack.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Utilitaires">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk" />
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

I can successfully apply it with GPO :)

If someone want to guide me on the taskbar block, you're welcome ! Otherwise i will post the solution when i'll solve it. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

In order for the Taskbar settings to work, you need to make sure the StartLayout.xml file has the schema for the taskbar listed. If you do not have the schema for the taskbar, you will get an "invalid" StartLayout file error during the import of the xml in Powershell. It needs to be added to the  tag and should look like this:

xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"

Comment: Where should this be added?  Which tag? --------EDIT: to anyone else who was struggling with this, that property needs to be added to the "CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection" tag, for instance:  <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout" PinListPlacement="Replace">

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation that you point to. If you look at the XML sample shown, the line in your file...

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

is not in the sample shown in the article.

A clean export on one of my Win10 FCU systems also do not show this line.

Did you modify this file manually and add this line?

If you did, remove it and try the import again.

Comment: Yep i added it like i see in several Technet pages. Originally, my xml does'nt have this line and did'nt work either :/